# removing all fragments so that onBackPressed closes app

Tags: android, fragment, onbackpressed

I currently have an android app that flows A -> B -> C -> D Launched in activity 1.

After D, I have activity 2 start and the following code runs to remove all fragments from the stack.

```
List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
if (fragments != null) {

    for (Fragment fragment : fragments) { 
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I return to activity 1 from activity 2, is that when I press the back key Fragment C animates back to screen. Fragment D does remove but A B C do not. I would like the app to close on backpress from activity 1.

I attached the code that removes my fragments here. Debugging shows that `fragment` does change with each loop.

Can anyone advise what is happening here?

Comment: what is desire behavior from D->C->B->A ? Why are you adding to backstack ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you're adding all the fragments to the back stack to begin with? Also, what fragment do you want shown when the user goes back from Activity 2 to Activity 1?

Comment: I add to the backstack because while in the fragments, I want to be able to navigate back to them if the back key is pressed.  the behavior is A>B>C>D> the open activity 2 if the call to the server is successful. If I return to activity 1 from activity 2 I do not want any of the fragments to appear on the backkeypress, I instead want it to exit the app.

Comment: I did not realize that `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();` does not remove from the backstack. I added code to remove from the backstack and that has given me the functionality I desire. Is my use of the backstack correct in this case? or is it useless?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite backpressed method and close the app, like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        finish(); // finish activity
}
```